# encrypt with mcrypt in ecb mode in c

Tags: c, encryption, arrays

I'm trying to encrypt a long char array with libmcrypt in c. I have a problem after I call my encrypt funktion more then 5 times. I can't see the mistake, but I'm getting strange output. If I have a 64 character plaintext it encrypts the first 32 characters and then for the last 32 I get twice the same 16 characters. I hope u get what I meen. Here my code:

```
char *Encrypt( char *key, char *message, int buff_len){

    unsigned char *Res;
    MCRYPT mfd; 
    char *IV;
    int i, blocks, key_size=16, block_size;




    mfd = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, NULL, "ecb", NULL);
    block_size = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(mfd);
    blocks = ceil((double)buff_len/block_size);

    mcrypt_generic_init(mfd, key, key_size, IV);
    Res = calloc(1, (blocks *block_size)+1);

    strncpy(Res, message, buff_len);
    //memset(message,'\0',blocks *block_size);
    mcrypt_generic(mfd,Res,(blocks *block_size));
    //printf("the encrypted in function(Encrypt) %s len %d\n",Res, strlen(Res));



    mcrypt_generic_deinit(mfd);
    mcrypt_module_close(mfd);

     return (Res);
```

}

and in the main I call:

```
    char seed[] = "thesecretmessage which I really want to check if if works", key1[]="abcdefghijklmnop";
int buff_len = strlen(seed), i;

char *encrypted = Encrypt(key1, seed, buff_len), *encrypted_pr=Encrypt(key1, encrypted, buff_len);
printf("the encrypted %s, %d\n", encrypted, strlen(encrypted));
printf("the encrypted_pr %s, %d\n", encrypted_pr, strlen(encrypted_pr));
for(i=0;i<15;i++){
    memcpy(encrypted2, Encrypt(key1, encrypted2, buff_len),64);
    printf("the encrypted_pr[%d] %s\n",i, encrypted_pr);
}
```

I'm really getting crazy on this. If I have a plaintext that's just 16 Bytes it works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thats a weird piece of code. Maybe you should explain what you are trying to do. Then check if the result matches your expectations. You are definitely doing one thing wrong though: bytes are not (printable) characters.

Comment: @owlstead Sorry, wrong word, a ment charecters not Bytes. I edited the post. Hopefully it's clearer now what my problem is.

Comment: Encryption might work on characters but it certainly produces bytes, which are non-printable, not terminated by a zero byte and cannot be processed with string functions.

Comment: @Codo so can you suggest something on how I can solve the problem. I really need to work with characters. And what is also strange, why does it work at first and then crash. I think that I'm not seeing a small mistake. Thanks alot!!

Comment: I recommend you work with bytes, i.e. an array of `unsigned char` and a separate integer value for storing the length. When you print the encrypted data, you need to display it as hexadecimal values as it cannot be directly printed. When you properly change your code, there shouldn't any string functions be left.

Comment: @Codo I tried  `unsigned char *Encrypt( unsigned char *key, unsigned char *message, int buff_len)` and `void hexdump(unsigned char *ciphertext, int len) { 
  int i,tmp;
  for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
    tmp = ciphertext[i] & 0xff; /** to avoid sign extension */
    printf("%02x ",tmp);
  }
  printf("\n");
}` but with no success.  Please help me out on this!!

Comment: I just wanted to say that I changed the encryption method in AES 128 cfb. Now it works without problems, so I guess it is something special about ecb. I suppose that it is only working with one block, but I didn't see that in the manual. Maybe someone can confirm that?